# vb.net Square Brackets Cause Error When Upgraded to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008-sp1

In the process of upgrading vb.net code from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2015, I am getting an **'Integer' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.** error on the following code:

```
[Integer].TryParse(...)
```

The error also occurs on similar code with [Date].TryParse. The target framework for both the original and upgraded code is .NET Framework 3.5. Upgrading the target framework doesn't matter. If I remove the square brackets, the code compiles. Does anyone know why this syntax works in Visual Studio 2008 but not Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: The Square brackets arent needed unless you whimsically use that as a name of a variable or property

Comment: It's probably a quirk that didn't get translated over to the Roslyn compiler. You can just remove the square brackets, they aren't needed if you're referring to the class.

Comment: I can't see why those brackets would be there in the first place.  The whole point of brackets is to indicate to the compiler that you want to use a keyword as an identifier.  In this case, you're calling a `Shared` member of a type so you specifically DO want `Integer` or `Date` to be interpreted as a keyword, i.e. their intrinsic types.  You'll sometimes see that done with `String` but that works because `String` is a .NET type.  `Integer` and `Date` are not .NET types.  The .NET types that correspond to those intrinsic types are `Int32` and `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Plutonix  @Blorgbeard and @jmcilhinney all answered in comments, you need to remove the square brackets. Converted to community wiki [in line with this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) recommendation, to remove from 'Unanswered' section.

> @ jmcilhinney
>
> The whole point of brackets is to indicate to the compiler that you want to use a keyword as an identifier. In this case, you're calling a Shared member of a type so you specifically DO want Integer or Date to be interpreted as a keyword, i.e. their intrinsic types. You'll sometimes see that done with String but that works because String is a .NET type. Integer and Date are not .NET types. The .NET types that correspond to those intrinsic types are Int32 and DateTime